# Returning multiple positions of multiple string matches within lines of text

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a text file such as:

```
>HiC_scaffold_1 LN:i:45809557 RC:i:152227 XC:f:0.987707
CAGGAAAGCCGCGTAAGTGAATATATGCAGCAACCTACCGAAAAGTGGGCCAATCCAACCAATCTTGCTTGCACAATGGAAAGAGCCACTGGTTTATCTCTCCATCGAATCAAATTAGCCAAAGGTGTGCGTTCATGAGCCCATGCTAAAGTTTCAATCAATTCTTGCCAATATCCACGCCAGGAAATTAAGAACATAAATCCAGTGCTGCAGC
>HiC_scaffold_2 LN:i:32008785 RC:i:102679 XC:f:0.981906
AAAGCTGCCCCTAGGCCGAACAAAATGGTCGGATGCGAAGAGAAATTGTTTGGCTCAAAATTTTACGAGCTTGTGCAGAACTTCAAGGCAATCATATCGGCAGGTGACACGAAGTGATTCGAGTTCGGCAGCTTTGCCCCTCCTTTTTCCTTGACGAAAGATAACTTTTTCTGAAAATAACACGTGCCCCGATTCCGGCCGAAATGACTCGAAT
>HiC_scaffold_3 LN:i:26569524 RC:i:79397 XC:f:0.996709
CCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAAACCCACCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCCCTAAACCCAAAACGCTGCCCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCGCAGCTAACCCTAAACC
```

I would like to find the positions within the lines that do not begin with ">" in which the patterns "GCAGC" or "GCTGC" appear.

Is there a way to use `sed` or `awk` to return both line numbers of matches, as well as the indexes of the matches within each line (i.e., the number of characters into each line at which each match begins)?

Thanks!

Comment: Can the target strings overlap? What should the output be for an input line like `fooGCAGCAGCAGCbar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that if overlapping target strings can occur you want to know about all of them, this will work using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
!/^>/ {
    while ( match($0,/GC[AT]GC/) ) {
        print NR, RSTART, substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) " " substr($0,RSTART+1)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
2 27 GCAGC
2 207 GCTGC
2 210 GCAGC
4 4 GCTGC
4 128 GCAGC
6 169 GCTGC
6 198 GCAGC
7 4 GCAGC
7 7 GCAGC
7 10 GCAGC
```

The above was run on this input file:

```
$ cat file
>HiC_scaffold_1 LN:i:45809557 RC:i:152227 XC:f:0.987707
CAGGAAAGCCGCGTAAGTGAATATATGCAGCAACCTACCGAAAAGTGGGCCAATCCAACCAATCTTGCTTGCACAATGGAAAGAGCCACTGGTTTATCTCTCCATCGAATCAAATTAGCCAAAGGTGTGCGTTCATGAGCCCATGCTAAAGTTTCAATCAATTCTTGCCAATATCCACGCCAGGAAATTAAGAACATAAATCCAGTGCTGCAGC
>HiC_scaffold_2 LN:i:32008785 RC:i:102679 XC:f:0.981906
AAAGCTGCCCCTAGGCCGAACAAAATGGTCGGATGCGAAGAGAAATTGTTTGGCTCAAAATTTTACGAGCTTGTGCAGAACTTCAAGGCAATCATATCGGCAGGTGACACGAAGTGATTCGAGTTCGGCAGCTTTGCCCCTCCTTTTTCCTTGACGAAAGATAACTTTTTCTGAAAATAACACGTGCCCCGATTCCGGCCGAAATGACTCGAAT
>HiC_scaffold_3 LN:i:26569524 RC:i:79397 XC:f:0.996709
CCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAAACCCACCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCCCTAAACCCAAAACGCTGCCCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCGCAGCTAACCCTAAACC
fooGCAGCAGCAGCbar
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much.  Probably all three of these solutions work, but I tried this one out of the full file and it seems to be working perfect.

Answer (score 2):

With `perl` (non-overlapping):

```sh
$ perl -lne 'if(!/^>/){print join " ", $., $-[0]+1, $& while /GCAGC|GCTGC/g}' ip.txt
2 27 GCAGC
2 207 GCTGC
4 4 GCTGC
4 128 GCAGC
6 169 GCTGC
6 198 GCAGC
```

- `if(!/^>/)` lines not starting with `>`
- `$.` gives line number
- `$-[0]` gives the starting position of the match (0-based index, so `1` is added)
- `$&` has the matched portion
- `join " "` use space as the separator to combine required values
- `while /GCAGC|GCTGC/g` loop over all the matches for the given regexp

To match overlapping cases as well, change the regexp to `/(?=(GCAGC|GCTGC))/g` so that the strings to match are now inside a lookahead capture group. This will try to match at every position without consuming the characters and the matched portion will be available from `$1`. If the search terms themselves overlap (for ex: `ABC` and `ABCD`), then whichever term is leftmost in the alternation gets precedence.

```sh
$ perl -lne 'if(!/^>/){print join " ", $., $-[0]+1, $1 while /(?=(GCAGC|GCTGC))/g}' ip.txt
2 27 GCAGC
2 207 GCTGC
2 210 GCAGC
4 4 GCTGC
4 128 GCAGC
6 169 GCTGC
6 198 GCAGC
```

With [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), which will likely be faster than other solutions. But the downside is that this doesn't filter out lines starting with `>` and works only for non-overlapping cases:

```sh
$ rg --vimgrep -o --no-filename 'GCAGC|GCTGC' ip.txt
2:27:GCAGC
2:207:GCTGC
4:4:GCTGC
4:128:GCAGC
6:169:GCTGC
6:198:GCAGC
```

- `--vimgrep` is designed for use with `vim`, which gives line and column numbers
- `-o` to get only matched portion instead of whole line
- `--no-filename` to avoid filename prefix in the output
- Use `--field-match-separator=' '` if you want space separator instead of `:` character

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your data is in a file `data.txt`, the simple solution would be:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n>";} \
  { for (j=1;j<=length($i)-4;j++) { \
    if (substr($i,j,5) == "GCAGC") { \
      print "entry " NR " column " j ": GCAGC" \
    } else if(substr($i,j,5) == "GCTGC") { \
      print "entry " NR " column " j ": GCTGC" \
    } \
  } \
}' data.txt
```

Here I assume that your entries are separated by "\n>" and print the entry number, because I assume that is what you want. Otherwise you can just leave out the first part and simply run

```
awk '{ for (j=1;j<=length($i)-4;j++) { \
    if (substr($i,j,5) == "GCAGC") { \
      print "line " NR " column " j ": GCAGC" \
    } else if(substr($i,j,5) == "GCTGC") { \
      print "line " NR " column " j ": GCTGC" \
    } \
  } \
}' data.txt
```

which gives you the line numbers. For more information, see the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf).

Comment: You should  mention that the first script requires GNU awk for multi-char RS, it won't work with a POSIX awk.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which handles overlapping patterns:

```
BEGIN {
    patternRegex = "GCAGC|GCTGC"
}

/^[^>]/ {
    offset = 0
    target = $0
    match(target, patternRegex)
    while (RSTART > 0) {
        matchedString = substr(target, RSTART, RLENGTH)
        printf "line %d: %s at position %d\n", NR, matchedString, offset + RSTART
        offset += RSTART + length("CG*") - 1
        target = substr(target, RSTART + length("CG*"))
        match(target, patternRegex)
    }
}
```

If the script is stored in `find-patterns.awk` and the input in `input.txt` we get the following output:

```
$ awk -f find-patterns.awk < input.txt 
line 2: GCAGC at position 27
line 2: GCTGC at position 207
line 2: GCAGC at position 210
line 4: GCTGC at position 4
line 4: GCAGC at position 128
line 6: GCTGC at position 169
line 6: GCAGC at position 198
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & ripgrep):

```
sed '/>/g' file | rg --column -o 'GC[AT]GC'| sed 'y/:/ /'
```

Blank lines containing `>`, use ripgrep to do the bulk of the work and clean up the result with a final sed invocation.

Alternative:

```
rg --column -o '>|GC[AT]GC' file | sed -E 'y/:/ /;/>/h;G;/^(\S* ).*\n\1/!P;d'
```

Kudos to Sundeep.