# Returning the position of pattern matches in a text file with multiple lines

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a long text file with the following format:

```
>foo_bar
TATGTTCTGCAACTGTATAATGGTATAAAAACATTGCAAAATGTAATGAAACTTGTTATTTTGTGAAATACATTCTATAAATATCACTATTTCATGAAAA
ATATTGAAAATCATTTATTTTCGACAAGTAGAACCATAGGTTCTGTAATTGTAAATAGTTCTGCAAACTTAACCTGTTTTGCAGAAGAATATGTTTTCAC
TAGTTAACTTGTAGAATGTTTAGGATTGTTAAAATTTTTAACAAAATAAGATTTTATAGAACATGATTTGCAAAATAACACATTTTGCAATATTTTTATA
CCATATATAGTTGCAGAACATATGGGGACTACGGGCAGCCGGTAAATATGTGGACTACATGGAACTTGTTCAGATACATCTGGAGCAAAGAGCCACCGCT
CTAAATTATCTCTTCTCATTTCCAGTATTATATCTCTCATGCTAAATTATCTCTACAAATCATGACCTCTCTTAGCAATCTCCCTGAGCATCTCCGTAGG
GAGCAGATATTCACCCGTCTTCCGATGAAAGACCTAATGGTCCTCGCATCTGCAAGTCATGTCTTGCGTTAATCTTTCTCTCTCTTTTTGTGGAATCCCA
TCTCTCCTCTTATCAACTAAACCAGATACAGTTTGCACCAACTTTCTTCACTCCCCTGTTACATGAGAAGGCCAGACTTAGGTAGCTTCTGAATCAGAAC
CCGGTCATTCCAAGCATGGGATTTCTTGTTGATCTCTTGTTTTTATGTAATAGTGATCATTTGATATCTGGTGTTGATGGGAATTCAGATGTATGGGACT
TTGTTTATTGTTGATGTGGAATTCTTATATTTTACTGTGTACTATAAAATTTTAGTGATACCTACTATCTATTGTATAAATTGATTAATTGATGTTCTTA
>bar_foo
TATGTTCTGCAACTGTATAATGGTATAAAAACATTGCAAAATGTAATGAAACTTGTTATTTTGTGAAATACATTCTATAAATATCACTATTTCATGAAAA
ATATTGAAAATCATTTATTTTCGACAAGTAGAACCATAGGTTCTGTAATTGTAAATAGTTCTGCAAACTTAACCTGTTTTGCAGAAGAATATGTTTTCAC
TAGTTAACTTGTAGAATGTTTAGGATTGTTAAAATTTTTAACAAAATAAGATTTTATAGAACATGATTTGCAAAATAACACATTTTGCAATATTTTTATA
CCATATATAGTTGCAGAACATATGGGGACTACGGTACTACGGTAAATATGTGGACTACATGGAACTTGTTCAGATACATCTGGAGCAAAGAGCCACCGCT
CTAAATTATCTCTTCTCATTTCCAGCTGCATATCTCTCATGCTAAATTATCTCTACAAATCATGACCTCTCTTAGCAATCTCCCTGAGCATCTCCGTAGG
GAGCAGATATTCACCCGTCTTCCGATGAAAGACCTAATGGTCCTCGCATCTGCAAGTCATGTCTTGCGTTAATCTTTCTCTCTCTTTTTGTGGAATCCCA
TCTCTCCTCTTATCAACTAAACCAGATACAGTTTGCACCAACTTTCTTCACTCCCCTGTTACATGAGAAGGCCAGACTTAGGTAGCTTCTGAATCAGAAC
CCGGTCATTCCAAGCATGGGATTTCTTGTTGATCTCTTGTTTTTATGTAATAGTGATCATTTGATATCTGGTGTTGATGGGAATTCAGATGTATGGGACT
TTGTTTATTGTTGATGTGGAATTCTTATATTTTACTGTGTACTATAAAATTTTAGTGATACCTACTATCTATTGTATAAATTGATTAATTGATGTTCTTA
```

I.e., there is a header line which begins with a "`>`", and then an arbitrary number of lines with no more than 100 letters in them.  I would like to find the positions within the non-header lines that match either "GCAGC" or "GCTGC".  Overlapping match sites would both get recorded individually.

An example output would be a three column text file where the first column contained the header line for that block of text minus the "`>`", the second column contained the start position of a pattern match (i.e., the number of characters into the text block, excluding line-break characters), and the third column recorded which of the two patterns were matched.  E.g.:

```
foo_bar 109 GCAGC
bar_foo 58289 GCTGC
```

Not sure how complex this task is, and in particular whether there is a memory-efficient way to perform this operation in a streaming fashion. `awk` or `sed` seem like two utilities which might work, but the required command is beyond my limited understanding of the programs.

Comment: You should have included your attempt to modify [the answer you got yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68433185/1745001) to an almost identical question to make this small change to it.

Comment: `the number of characters into the text block, excluding line-break characters` - I'd suggest to use a tool that understands fasta format, for ex: `biopython` module.

Answer (score 1):

A tiny tweak on [yesterdays answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68433185/1745001):

```
sub(/^>/,"") {
    hdr = $0
    next
}
{
    while ( match($0,/GC[AT]GC/) ) {
        print hdr, RSTART, substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) " " substr($0,RSTART+1)
    }
}
```

Please get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn the basics of awk.